# How to run a jquery function after i added css

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, styles

I have this line:

```
$('body>header:last a,body>header:last div,body>header:last h1').css("-webkit-transition", "opacity 0.5s ease-in");
```

and i would like the rest of the javascript to run AFTER that style gets added.
I currently use a timer

```
setTimeout(function () {
                    $('body>header:not(:last),body>footer:not(:last),body>#content:not(:last)').remove();                   
                    $('body>header,body>footer,body>#content').removeAttr('style'); },1000);
```

But somehow the css gets added when the timer executes and not before it.
Any idea why this happens? if not is there a way to force the timeout function to run after adding the css

Comment: You mean you want the JavaScript code to execute after the CSS transition finished? I don't think that this is possible. But as you are already using jQuery, you can use it for these effects. It will also work in non-webkit browsers then.

Comment: @Felix Kling that is not smooth on mobile devices so i need to use css3 :)

Comment: what is the layout of the page in js code? Is it possible to post the skeleton of the page?

Comment: @cfarm54 
javascript: http://pastebin.com/Ay0GFQp9
HTML: http://pastebin.com/t7mC62MR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer guys! i was not a jquery problem but a css3 trick.

In order to do the animation, the opacity of the element had to be set to 1. That happened after that 1 second delay.
I did not undserstand the link between the 2 but now i do. So what I did is just change this:

```
$('body>header:last a,body>header:last div,body>header:last h1').css({'-webkit-transition': 'opacity 0.5s ease-in','opacity':'1'});
```

I simple add opacity:1 to the css which was previously at 0 so that the transition starts.

Sorry for the headache and thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Make the first code run in it's own function and give it a callback function

```
function addStyle(callback)
{
    $('body>header:last a,body>header:last div,body>header:last h1').css("-webkit-transition", "opacity 0.5s ease-in");

    if (typeof callback !== 'undefined') callback();
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
addStyle(function(){

    // Do other stuff here after css is added...

});
```

Comment: In this case it would be easier to just place the statements one after another. There is no need to use a callback system.

Comment: @SnippetSpace: I'm just saying that the code given in this answer has the same effect has putting the three statements one after another. And this does not seem to work for you...

Comment: solution does not function :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you declare setTimeout outside of the loadPage and then call it within document.ready?

Comment: that is not possible since the timed events needs to happen after the ajax call. So if there is a connection error nothing should happen. I fixed it btw, no need to think about this any longer, thanks anyway :)